# Writing to Excel from Python and saving the key cell in Python

Tags: python, excel

I am simulating the change in a certain cell value in Excel through changing 3 adjacent columns in Excel by commanding through Python. These three columns' values will be chosen from a combination of `12 * 11 * 9` (1188 iterations) values.

[Main Excel sheet and available columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOSL.png)

[Columns that are available for the Katode column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5DwK.png)

[Columns that are available for the Anode column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dZ6a.png)

[Columns that are available for the Lam column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptdev.png)

My code so far as follows, unfortunately I don't know how to iterate the combinations of avaliable columns and convey them to the calculation and store the key value:

```
import pandas as pd

  
path="C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\Book1.xlsx"

dfff = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0, engine='openpyxl')

kathode_cols = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\Book1.xlsx',sheet_name='Katodes',header=0, engine='openpyxl')

anode_cols = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\Book1.xlsx',sheet_name='Anodes',header=0, engine='openpyxl')

Lam_cols = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\Book1.xlsx',sheet_name='Lambs',header=0, engine='openpyxl')

for i in range(len(kathode_cols.columns)):
    dfff.loc[:, 'Katode'] = kathode_cols.loc[:, kathode_cols.columns[i]]
    for j in range(len(anode_cols.columns)):
        dfff.loc[:, 'Anode'] = anode_cols.loc[:, anode_cols.columns[j]]
        for k in range(len(Lam_cols.columns)):
            dfff.loc[:, 'Lam'] = Lam_cols.loc[:, Lam_cols.columns[k]]

KeyValue{i,j,k}=dfff['Key'][0]
```

I have just started modelling in Python, hopefully what I am asking is not too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, first you have to provide the path to your file to `read_excel`:

```
dfff = pd.read_excel('path/to/your/file.xslx', sheet_name='Sheet1',
                     header=0)
```

and than you could store the other values in different DataFrames:

```
kathode_cols = pd.read_excel('path/to/kathode_columns.xslx',
                              sheet_name=<whatever sheetname you used>,
                              header=0)
```

and so on for the other files.

And than you could say something like:

```
for i in range(len(kathode_cols.columns)):
    dfff.loc[:, 'Kathode'] = kathode_cols.loc[:, kathode_cols.columns[0]]
    # do some further calculations...
```

What should replace the values in `dff` in the column 'Kathode' with the values in one of the columns of 'kathode_columns'. And than you can do further calculations or whatever you plan to do.

I hope that helps you?

**EDIT:**

little example showing you what I mean. I don't have your data and I was too lazy to type, so I just used some fantasy numbers

```
import pandas as pd

# making your DataFrame
dfff = {'Kathode': [0 for _ in range(10)],
        'Anode': [2 for _ in range(10)],
        'Lam': [4 for _ in range(10)]}

dfff = pd.DataFrame(dfff)

# making the other DataFrames containing the different comuns
kathode_cols = {i: [(1.5+i)*j for j in range(10)] for i in range(5)}
kathode_cols = pd.DataFrame(kathode_cols)

anode_cols = {i: [(0.5+i)*j for j in range(10)] for i in range(5)}
anode_cols= pd.DataFrame(anode_cols)

lam_cols = {i: [(1+i)*j for j in range(10)] for i in range(5)}
lam_cols= pd.DataFrame(lam_cols)

# here go your results
results = []

# iterate throug all the possible combinations
for a in kathode_cols.columns:
    dfff.loc[:, 'Kathode'] = kathode_cols[a]
    for b in anode_cols.columns:
        dfff.loc[:, 'Anode'] = anode_cols[b]
        for c in lam_cols:
            dfff.loc[:, 'Lam'] = lam_cols[c]
            # do your calculations here
            result = dfff['Kathode'].sum() + dfff['Anode'].sum() - 2*dfff['Lam'].sum()
            # store your results
            results.append(result)
```

This does some fantasy calculation with the different columns and stores it in a list - everything in python. It's certainly not the most efficient implementation, but I think, it should do it.

Hope, this helps you out

Comment: Andre this certainly helps me a lot. But how can I iterate different combis of the columns and store the key value (the cell value in excel)  for each iteration? Basically i don't compute anything mathematically in Python, but only in Excel.

Comment: do you realy have to stay in Excel? Because I dont have any clue, how to trigger a calculation in Esxcel from within a python script. If it is possible, I would recommend you to just stay in python. I prepare a you a little example script, showing you what I mean ;)